# Why implemetion of interface (method name) obfuscated, even if '-keep interface' present at proguad

Tags: java, android, proguard

I have Android project. Project use some java library.
I add to `proguard.cfg` line:

`-keep class my.library.package.**    { *; }
 -keep interface my.library.package.** { *; }`

After build I see, that yes, all classes and interfaces from package `my.library.package` have no changes.

I have class at my main project, that implement interface from `my.library.package`. And what's I see? Name of implemented method are obfuscated.

More details. I have interface in `my.library.package`:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
     void myMethod();
}
```

I have class, not at `my.library.package`:

```
public class MyClass implements IMyInterface  {

        // ...   

        void myMethod() {
        // ..
    }
}
```

After building I see class as *.class file:

```
// It's ok, that class MyClass now have name e.   
public class e implements IMyInterface  {

        // Own variables and methods of class are obfuscated. Its' ok.

        // Why here a(), not myMethod()?
        void a() {
        // Here obfuscated code too. It's ok.
    }
}
```

**UPD**
Of course, I can add new line to `proguard.cfg`:

```
-keep class com.some.package.MyClass {
    void myMethod();
}
```

But I can use a lot of open source libraries and makes no sense to obfuscate this code. So, for each interface I needed add line to `proguard.cfg`. Nightmare!

Comment: What's your questions?

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard doesn't rename kept interface methods that are implemented by other classes. Otherwise most applications would not work anymore.

You probably have a misconfiguration regarding your -injars, -libraryjars options and you should already see some warnings in your build log.